# Which table column to Index?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table which has columns A, B, C, D.

I have an application which searches a word in ALL the columns of the table.

If I want to index the table so that search happens faster, which column should I index?

How will the index command look?

**EDIT:**
Actually, I have 27 columns of Languages (e.g. English, German, etc). I have an application which searches a word in all the languages and returns a result.

How to do index this table to ensure faster search result?

Comment: These kinds of questions are very RDBMS specific (and with MySQL, possibly storage engine specific). You've tagged this question with 3 of them, and the answer is different on each of those 3! Your question also seems to assume you have to pick a column, when, in at least some of those RDBMS, you can define a single index that includes all 4 columns.

Comment: What type of data do you have in these Columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a full-text index on all columns.

Unfortunately SQLite doesn't support full-text indexes by default. You have to compile it with optional full-text index support enabled.

As unhelpful as it may be to just point you at the docs for SQLite's Full-Text indexing, here they are:
http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html

Comment: I am using SQLite as my database

Comment: SQLite does full-text indexing but as an optional module you must specify at compile-time. See http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html

Answer (score 0):

You should either use a full-text index, if your database supports this, or put a "normal" index on each column with a "create index" statement. The syntax might differ from database to database, so I can't give you a code sample here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have only those columns?
how large is your database? how often your data is refreshed. 
What kind of queries are you performing (like queries mostly).
What is your database engine?

your answers to these may lead to,
no index at all,
indexes on each of those 4 columns,
a full-text index.

Comment: I dont have experience with SQLite. as suggested visit http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html

Answer (score 0):

Please notice these Links about:

[SQL Performance Tuning using Indexes](http://odetocode.com/code/237.aspx) and [The SQLite Query Planner](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html)

and specially the section 
 ***Building The Best Index*** in the 1st Link

You may want to consider the option of 4 Indexes, one per column, so up to the language you are searching in, you can sort using the Index you need.